# Word for disproportionate punishment?

Tags: single-word-requests

I read about somebody who was sentenced and put in prison for a very long time for a petty crime. I think the word began with a p...

The word means punishing somebody in a completely disproportionate manner.

For example, Matthew stole a candy bar from a 7-Eleven and got put in jail for 17 years.

Comment: **ᴍᴏᴅᴇʀᴀᴛᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ:** Answers go in the answer-box, not in the comment box.

Comment: @tchrist, I've seen people bashed for posting answers that aren't practically perfect. I know that that's why I don't post an answer before commenting it tentatively first, and waiting for the OP to approve it. It may not be what's stated in the rules, but I suspect that for many users, it's necessary to protect themselves from this oft-cruel site.

Comment: @vanderpn if you think this site is hard on people, just try StackOverflow and see how good you have it here.

Comment: [_Excuse me, Mr. President, but what else is there?  The **disproportional response**_.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtrX9rZl-j4&feature=youtu.be&t=103)

Comment: *Tough on crime* is a punitive approach which allows the law to treat criminals harshly. By the way, I guess the word that you can't remember is *penal*.

Comment: Penalised: 1. Subject to penalty or punishment 2. To put (someone) at an unfair disadvantage. Could it be 'penalised'?

Comment: @vanderpn: amen, I have the same reaction on lots of SE sites (including but not limited to SO).

Comment: Is it possible that the word you remember is *punitive*? That word by itself simply means "concerned with punishment" but you may have its meaning confused. Punitive action may be considered severe when no punishment is expected in the first place. But it has know meaning within the spectrum of the degree of punishment.

Comment: just FYI a common phrase is "the punishment doesn't fit the crime".

Comment: I don't think you are going to get it in a single word

Answer (score 45):

***Draconian***

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/Draconian

> Draconian
> Use the word Draconian (or lowercase draconian) to describe laws or rules that are really harsh and repressive.
>
> In ancient Athens, Draco was a guy who made some seriously strict laws. So rules that are too restrictive — or just plain unfair — are called Draconian. Sentencing someone to 10 years in prison for littering would be Draconian. Some people think Singapore's chewing gum ban is Draconian.
>
> This is a strong word, so if your parents make you do chores, they aren't being Draconian. But if they make you do chores for five hours every day, that's another story.

Comment: Whether Draconian is capitalized seems to be a matter of style; I usually don't see it capitalized in the US.

Comment: yeah i wouldn't capitalize it.  I just cut and paste that.

Answer (score 25):

The word you are seeking is ***disproportionate***.

OD:

> [***disproportionate***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disproportionate):
>   too large or too small in comparison with something else: *‘people on
>   lower incomes spend a disproportionate amount of their income on fuel’
>   ‘persistent offenders were given sentences that were disproportionate
>   to the offences they had committed’*

Your example, "Matthew stole a candy bar from a 7-Eleven and got put in jail for 17 years," exemplifies a ***disproportionate*** punishment ... and the concept of ***disproportionality***.

Comment: @dacsaunders For the record, the original title question called for an alternative to *inproportional* or *unproportional*, I don't remember which. I object to your changing it, or if you didn't change it, I object to whoever did change it.

Comment: I object to ignoring what the question was actually looking for, which was  not just the correct form of "unproportional".  This was clear from before the edit, which you can easily view [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/367153/revisions) or by clicking on the edit timestamp below the post text.

Comment: @MatthewRead That's not clear at all. I hope you voted every answer down.

Comment: Actually, this answer is is fine. It is simply stating that one entirely valid word in normal use in this situation actually **is** *disproportionate.*

Answer (score 21):

I think the word you are half-remembering is ***punitive*** - inflicting or intended to inflict punishment; retributive, punishing (OED).

Note, however, that punitive means '*punishing*' and not '*disproportionately punishing*'.  Even when used in law (as in *punitive damages*) the sense is that punitive damages compensate the wronged party and *also* punish (within reasonable bounds of proportionality!) the wrong-doer.

To have the sense sought by the OP you would need to say something like ***excessively punitive***.

Setting aside the OP's request for a word beginning with 'P', *draconian* seems like the best fit for the sense described.

Answer (score 8):

Another phrase you might have heard is **cruel and unusual punishment**. It's a little more than simply disproportionate but it's a related concept and an important term of art in (international) human rights law.

Comment: Yep, the phrase "cruel and unusual punishment" is most notable for appearing in the US Bill of Rights (and it is purportedly a paraphrasing of a provision in the English Bill of Rights of 1689).  It is, alas, rather vaguely defined, but has served as the basis for limiting disproportionate punishment in a number of key legal decisions over the past two centuries.

Comment: "punishment that is very harsh and too severe for the crime" - Merriam Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruel%20and%20unusual%20punishment)

Answer (score 6):

**[Unfitting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unfitting)**

> *"He was given 30 years for stealing an apple? That seems unfitting."*

Answer (score 3):

**Inordinate**: unusually or disproportionately large.

So instead of:

> Matthew stole a candy bar from a 7-Eleven and got put in jail for 17 years.

You could write, *Matthew stole a candy bar from a 7-Eleven and was jailed for an inordinate amount of time*

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with punishment, it's effectively just a synonym for "disproportionate" alone.

Comment: Then I vote 'cruel and unusual punishment'

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for an adjective, I suppose you could use the word ***incommensurate***, as in 'a punishment that seems incommensurate with the crime committed'.

Answer (score 1):

Such a severe punishment dished out to deter others from committing the same *crime* is sometimes called ***exemplary***.

Macmillan:

> **[exemplary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/exemplary#exemplary_5)**
>   *ADJECTIVE FORMAL*
>
> **2** an exemplary punishment is extremely severe, so that other people will be afraid to commit a similar crime

Answer (score 0):

In the US there are maximum sentencing guidelines so

***throw the book at***

[throw the book at someone](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/throw-the-book-at-someone)

> To impose a severe punishment, esp to assign a maximum sentence to a
>   criminal; treat mercilessly : If he catches you one more time he'll
>   throw the book at you

Answer (score 0):

Persecution

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persecution#English
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/persecute

They say the same thing. It's used mainly for being punished for belonging to a disliked group, or for a campaign to punish or hold back a disliked group.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps **[profuse](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20profuse&oq=define%20profuse)**: (especially of something offered or discharged) exuberantly plentiful; abundant.

> I offered my profuse apologies.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with punishment, and even "profuse punishment" is pretty bizarre.